# Mapstruct set whole property to null instead of all properties in nested class

Tags: java, mapstruct

My current mapper looks like this:

```
    public abstract OwnerResponse toOwnerResponse(Owner owner);
```

A `Owner` has basic properties like, `id`, `name` etc. Mapping these works properly.
Now `Owner` also has a `address` property which will be an `Address` class (with `zip`, `street` etc). In some instances, the address can be empty. This will look lile this in json response:
`{"id": 1, "name": "Peter", "address": {"zip": null, "street": null}}`

Instead of that, I would like to have the whole `Owner.address` to be `null` instead of having a whole `Address` class that has a lot of `null` properties. Example:
`{"id": 1, "name": "Peter", "address": null}`

How do I achieve this?

Comment: you can use expression like : @Mapping(target = "address", expression = "java(null)") or just ignore this field @Mapping(target = "address", ignore = true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem actually was that the mapper had [NullValueMappingStrategy](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/NullValueMappingStrategy.html) set like this: `@Mapper(nullValueMappingStrategy = NullValueMappingStrategy.RETURN_DEFAULT, componentModel = "spring")` Since I had no default values defined, it just put an instance of `Address` there with all properties set to `null`, if the source value was `null`. After I removed this, the `Address` was properly set to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The @Mapping annotation specifies to use a custom qualifiedByName method toAddressResponse() for the address field. This method checks if the Address object is null or if all of its fields are null. If so, it returns null; otherwise, it proceeds with the normal mapping.

```
@Mapper
public interface OwnerMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "address", qualifiedByName = "toAddressResponse")
    OwnerResponse toOwnerResponse(Owner owner);

    @Named("toAddressResponse")
    default AddressResponse toAddressResponse(Address address) {
        if (address == null || (address.getZip() == null && address.getStreet() == null)) {
            return null;
        }
        return new AddressResponse(address.getZip(), address.getStreet());
    }
}
```